# How to call "page specific menu items" in template

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, menus

I have installed a plugin for giving custom command for menu to display on each [Page Specific Menu Items](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-specific-menu-items/), now I need to display these menus on theme header.

Can I use anything like wp_nav_menu().

Please suggest.

Comment: this plugin uses existing menus. you shouldnt need to do anything else

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?! Please accept and upvote if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned **clearly** in the plugin's page:

How to make this plugin work?

> - Create a menu from appearance > menus
> - Select the menu you want to use from settings > PS MenuItems > Select Menu
> - Assign the menu to menu location from appearance > menus
> - Check the items you want to hide from pages > edit > Page Specific Menu Items
> - View the page and the selected items should be gone.

How does this plugin works?

> - This plugin adds 'hide_this_item' class to selected menu items.

Shall I install plugin first or create menu first?

> - It does not matter whether you first create menu and then install this plugin or vice versa.

Does this plugin works on custom post type pages?

> - Yes it does.

This plugin does not work for me?

> - It should since it works by adding class. Only case it does not work is when `hide_this_item` rules is overridden by other styles (having low value in specificity). This is not actually this plugins issue.